# Deprecated ViewPropTypes react native

Tags: react-native, babeljs, react-props, deprecated

I am trying the solution here and defined my babel.config.js as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
          tests: ['./tests/'],
          '@components': './src/components',
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['.'],
        resolvePath(sourcePath, currentFile) {
          if (
            sourcePath === 'react-native' &&
            currentFile.includes('react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js')
          ) {
            console.log('resolver', sourcePath, currentFile);
            return path.resolve(__dirname, 'resolver/react-native');
          }
          return undefined;
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

and in my resolver i have done this:

```
import * as ReactNative from 'react-native';

delete ReactNative.ColorPropType;
delete ReactNative.EdgeInsetsPropType;
delete ReactNative.ImagePropTypes;
delete ReactNative.PointPropType;
delete ReactNative.TextInputPropTypes;
delete ReactNative.TextPropTypes;
delete ReactNative.ViewPropTypes;

module.exports = {
  ...ReactNative,
  get ViewPropTypes() {
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedViewPropTypes');
  },

  get ColorPropType() {
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedColorPropType');
  },

  get EdgeInsetsPropType() {
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedEdgeInsetsPropType');
  },

  get PointPropType() {
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedPointPropType');
  },
};
```

But it is giving me error as below:

error: index.js: Duplicate plugin/preset detected.
If you'd like to use two separate instances of a plugin,
they need separate names, e.g.

plugins: [
['some-plugin', {}],
['some-plugin', {}, 'some unique name'],
]

How i can solve this. I think it is related to babel.config.js file ... how can i define my babel.config correctly?

Answer (score 0):

using patch-package

create file patches/react-native-camera+4.2.1.patch

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js 
b/node_modules/react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js
index b7a271a..ea3c6d2 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@ import {
   findNodeHandle,
   Platform,
   NativeModules,
-  ViewPropTypes,
+  ViewProps,
   requireNativeComponent,
   View,
   ActivityIndicator,
@@ -394,7 +394,7 @@ export default class Camera extends React.Component<PropsType, StateType> {
   };

   static propTypes = {
-    ...ViewPropTypes,
+    ...ViewProps,
     zoom: PropTypes.number,
     useNativeZoom: PropTypes.bool,
     maxZoom: PropTypes.number,
```

then add script in package.json

```
"postinstall": "npx patch-package",
```

Comment: this is is not a good solution as everytime i install a new package i have to do it again

Comment: nope, when you install new package, it auto change node_module
You can view docs at `patch-package npm`